# Using app function from {terra} package on raster stacks? (in parallel)

Tags: r, raster, tiles, terra

I have four high resolution rasters for a country. I have split each raster into tiles and done some other processing to them. I now want to apply a function to each cell, of each 'stack' of the raster tiles, to produce one set of output tiles. The function is a little complex. I have tried to synthesise some data below to reproduce my current approach. It works (ish) but I'm convinced that there's a better way to do this. To use parallel processing  on my unix box, I simply swap **mapply** for **mcmapply**, but I haven't done that in the example below as I presume many will be working on Windows machines. I'd welcome ideas on my approach and particularly optimisation.

```
library("terra")
library("glue")

## Make some toy data

dir.create("temp_folder")
dir.create("result_folder")

x <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10)

a <- rast(ncol = 100, nrow = 100)
some_values <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100))
ind <- which(some_values %in% sample(some_values, 15))
some_values[ind] <- NA
values(a) <- some_values
a_tiles <- makeTiles(a, x, glue("temp_folder/tile_a_{1:100}.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)

b <- rast(ncol = 100, nrow = 100)
some_values <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100))
ind <- which(some_values %in% sample(some_values, 15))
some_values[ind] <- NA
values(b) <- some_values
b_tiles <- makeTiles(b, x, glue("temp_folder/tile_b_{1:100}.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)

c <-rast(ncol = 100, nrow = 100)
some_values <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100))
ind <- which(some_values %in% sample(some_values, 15))
some_values[ind] <- NA
values(c) <- some_values
c_tiles <- makeTiles(c, x, glue("temp_folder/tile_c_{1:100}.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)

d <- rast(ncol = 100, nrow = 100)
some_values <- as.integer(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100))
ind <- which(some_values %in% sample(some_values, 15))
some_values[ind] <- NA
values(d) <- some_values
d_tiles <- makeTiles(d, x, glue("temp_folder/tile_d_{1:100}.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)

## Outer function so that this can be used in parallel ? But maybe this is a silly way to do it?
outer_function <- function(a_tiles, b_tiles, c_tiles, d_tiles, output_files) {

    one_a_tile  <- rast(unlist(a_tiles))
    one_b_tile  <- rast(unlist(b_tiles))
    one_c_tile  <- rast(unlist(c_tiles))
    one_d_tile  <- rast(unlist(d_tiles))
    output_file <- output_files

    # I replace any NAs with 0 as an NA will break my 'if' statement of the inner_function.
    # I get Error in if (z["a"] <= z["b"]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    one_a_tile[is.na(one_a_tile)] <- 0
    one_b_tile[is.na(one_b_tile)] <- 0
    one_c_tile[is.na(one_c_tile)] <- 0
    one_d_tile[is.na(one_d_tile)] <- 0

    z <- sds(one_a_tile, one_b_tile, one_c_tile, one_d_tile)

    ## Inner function that actually does the work I want doing
    inner_function <- function(z) {

        names(z) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

        if (z['a'] <= z['b'])  {
            y <- rowSums(cbind((z['c'] + z['a'] * 10),
                               (z['c'] + z['a'] * 20)))
            }
        if (z['a'] >= z['b'])  {
             y <- rowSums(cbind((z['c'] + z['a'] * 40),
                                (z['c'] + z['a'] * 10)))
             }
        if (z['a'] == z['b'])  {
            y <- rowSums(cbind((z['c'] + z['a'] * 60),
                               (z['c'] + z['a'] * 10)))
            }
        y <- ifelse(y == 0, NA, y)
        return(y)

    }

    app(z,
        inner_function,
        filename = output_file,
        overwrite = TRUE,
        wopt = list(datatype = "INT4U"))
    
    return(output_file)

        }

results <- mapply(outer_function,
                    a_tiles = a_tiles,
                    b_tiles = b_tiles,
                    c_tiles = c_tiles,
                    d_tiles = d_tiles,
                    output_files = output_files <- glue("result_folder/result_tile_{1:length(d_tiles)}.tif"))

names(results) <- NULL

unlink("temp_folder", recursive = TRUE)
unlink("result_folder", recursive = TRUE)
```